# Авторизация на сайте на зеркале сайта

Tags: php

Добрый день. Возможно ли одновременная авторизация на основном домене и его зеркале?
Если да, то как?  Желательно работа с куками, нежели с сессиями. Но я так понимаю куки записываются только для одного домена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скопируйте решение Яндекса

> У яндекса все логин-формы ведут в одну точку (**passport.yandex.ru**) и передают вместе с логином и паролем URL возвращения. Паспорт лезет в базу, проверяет валидность пароля и, если всё ок, то показывает на короткое время пользователю страницу с невидимыми картинками, которые загружаются со всех доменов, где нужна авторизация. там всё очень хитро в плане секьюрити, токены и всё-такое, но это уже детали. короче, браузер пользователя посылает запросы по этим картинкам, и по этим запросам происходит собственно авторизация. после того, как все картинки загрузились, юзера редиректит обратно туда, откуда он пришёл. не очень изящная, на мой вкус, схема, но, видимо, лучше не существует.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать iframe'ом, т.е. например на сайте site1.ru при нажатии на кнопку авторизваться пользователь авторизуется, а также появляется невидимый iframe с авторизацией на `site2.ru/auth.php?login=test&pass=7624` или не iframe, а просто считать     `site2.ru/auth.php?login=test&pass=7624` через `file_get_contents`, т.е.:

```
<?php
//.... авторизация, если всё введено верно, а также
file_get_contents("http://site2.ru/auth.php?login=".$login."&pass=".$pass);
?>
```